# Markup and Markdown Math Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Peninsula Hardware buys cabinet doors for $25 less 40%, 10%, and 4% . The stores overhead expenses are 35% of cost and the required profit is 15 % of cost. For how much should the cabinet doors be sold?

I am confused on which formulas to use and how to input these numbers into the formulas. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If overhead expenses plus required profit is $50\%$ of cost, then retail price should be $\ge cost \times 1.5$, so start by determining the cost of each type of door.

Comment: I don't think they are different types of doors. If they were, we would need the proportion of each.

Comment: What is 40%, 10%, 4%?? your question is not clear, please make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The only interpretation I can think of that yields an answer with the given data is that the discounts of 40%, 10% and 4% are successive discounts.

Then Cost $= 25(1-0.40)(1-0.10)(1-0.04) = 12.96$

To cover overheads of 35% and profit of 15% (**each on cost**),

selling price needed = $12.96 \times 1.5 = 19.44$